# PHP Date for the second week in April

Tags: php, date

I have an event that begins the second Wednesday of April and ends that following Sunday -- every year. I need to add some code in the header of the website that automatically changes the dates at the turn of every calendar year. I've read a few things that almost get me there, but haven't found anything that works exactly.

Anyone have any solutions to this?

Date format would look like this: April 9-13, 2014

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
    $start = new DateTime('second wednesday of april');
    $end = clone $start;         
    $end->modify('+4 days');

    echo $start->format('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $end->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use relative formatting with PHP's `strtotime`. In your example:

```
$next_year = strtotime( '%G', strtotime( '+1 Year' ));
$start     = strtotime( 'Second Wednesday of April ' . $next_year ));
$end       = strtotime( '+4 Days', $start );
```

With that start date and end date, you can use `strftime` to format the end result however you'd like:

```
echo strftime('%F', $start) . ' - ' . strftime('%F', $end);
```